# how to store result of WPS in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, wps

I'd like to save WPS result (ie. image file) in Geoserver's file system.
I found out Geoserver put the result in temp/wps folder. 
Can I change  it to specific folder with specific file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder is named "temp" because it's temporary storage of results. If you actually want to save them on disk you can either:

- Call the WPS from another program residing on the same machine, grab the results and save them where you want
- Chain the call with another process that will save the results locally as its main job. There is for example a StoreCoverage process saving locally raster results. While there is no vector equivalent, one could be created.